# How can I see the password of another user in Linux?

Tags: users, password, root

I made 4 users on my server, but unfortunately I changed the password of the "first" user while configuring the server, but I don't know how I changed it.
How can I see the password of users in root?

Comment: note that you cannot "see" other password, you can change them as root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As root you can change any users password by using the "passwd" command followed by the username;

```
passwd username
```

This will then prompt you to enter the new password twice.

To clarify there is no way to see an existing users password.

Comment: I tried it, but it said:
passwd: The modul is unidentified.
passwd: Password unchanged.

Comment: What Operating System is this server running?

Comment: @blackcornail Did you copy-paste this error message? It indicates some kind of misconfiguration. Echoing Dayvo, tell us exactly what operating system you're running (what version etc.), and anything you think might be relevant about its configuration (e.g. do you use NIS/LDAP/…?)